# Virtual attribute to set published_at for a Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a post model with a datetime field called "published_at". On my form I have a checkbox for an attribute named "publish_now" (see below). I want "published_at" to be set to the Time.now() when the user checks the checkbox for my virtual attribute :publish_now.

```
<input class="boolean optional" id="post_publish_now" name="post[publish_now]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

Here is my create and update methods in the controller:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  if current_user
    @post.author_id == current_user.id
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And here is my model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "author_id"

  attr_accessible :author_id, :content, :published_at, :title, :publish_now

  validates_presence_of :content, :title

  def publish_now
    !published_at.nil?
  end

  def publish_now=(value)
    if value == "1" && published_at.nil?
      published_at = Time.now()
    end 
  end
end
```

This is my best guess of how it should work based on the railscast on virtual attributes, but it's not saving a value for published_at. Any suggestions where the problem might be?

UPDATE: (the form view)

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.input :content, input_html: { cols: 100, rows: 10, class: "
    span5" } %>
  <% if @post.published_now == false %>
    <%= f.input :publish_now, as: :boolean %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE Example Log:

```
Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-31 14:14:49 -0500
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zlZ3s18VXwEvONIkk1CZAYESAEAxPP1OKcUtiyEuZgA=", "post"=>{"title"=>"big big love a doodle", "content"=>"aksdfj;skjf;kasjdf; lkj af;lk ;askdfj ;lk ;laf; ksd ;f", "publish_now"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("author_id", "content", "created_at", "published_at", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["author_id", nil], ["content", "aksdfj;skjf;kasjdf; lkj af;lk ;askdfj ;lk ;laf; ksd ;f"], ["created_at", Wed, 31 Oct 2012 14:14:49 CDT -05:00], ["published_at", nil], ["title", "big big love a doodle"], ["updated_at", Wed, 31 Oct 2012 14:14:49 CDT -05:00]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts/5
Completed 302 Found in 18ms (ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
```

Comment: Please add the content of your view! Have you checked what is the real value of the checkbox?

Comment: It would help to see the portion of the view with the checkbox (or, alternately, to log/debug the contents of `params` as you enter the controller method).

Comment: At the top is the input field as it appears in the html, at the bottom is the actual view app/views/posts/_form.html.erb

Comment: Don't you have to compare the value of publish_now setter to a boolean value, since you defined it as a boolean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in this line

```
published_at = Time.now()
```

It should be

```
self.published_at = Time.now()
```

The parenthesis are also optional.
If you assign to something then Ruby will assume it's a local variable unless you explicitly provide the object, only then can Ruby know it's actually a method you want to call (published_at= method). This is a common gotcha moment in Ruby.

What happens in your code is that a new local variable published_at is created. See http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html at "Using Accessors Within a Class" for more information.

When reading attributes like that you don't need to prefix by self, however, because Ruby will not assume something is a local variable until you assign it. So before published_at=..., Ruby will treat published_at as a method call, after you do published_at=... (without self in front), it will treat published_at as a local variable. Only then you would have to use self.published_at to actually call the method instead of reading the local variable. For the attribute writter (ends with =), you always need to prefix with the object. You can alternatively use the attributes hash, that way you don't need to prefix by self:

```
attributes["published_at"] = whatever
```

Comment: Why does ruby behave differently inside attribute writers?  Where is this documented (besides that book)?

Comment: What do you mean with "inside" attribute writers? The reason why you can't call attribute writers as you can attribute readers (without the object) is because of performance. To make it work the interpreter would have to check every time you assign something if it's a method or local variable, which would make this assignment much slower in both cases. But even more, Ruby could then not determine when compiling a method how many local variables it has (because it can only know if it's a method call at runtime). This would be disaster for performance.